# Is programming using the Arduino IDE suitable for commercial products?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, embedded

I need to program a microcontroller in such a way that I EXACTLY know what it will be doing, because it is for a project that requires high levels of reliability (similar to automotive products).

I know my way around in C (started 9 years ago) so ideally I would code everything myself using the ATMEL official framework, compile it with AVR-GCC and burn the EEPROM with AVRDude. There is also the method of uploading the .hex to the bootloader already burned to avoid using an in circuit programmer (done by Arduino). No surprises.

However, the framework is -obviously- very low level. I don't really have the time to manipulate the registers directly every time I use an ADC or send data on the USART (actually more prone to error). So I thought the Arduino library can't be unreliable given all the time it's been out there (it has the C++ syntax but why not).

But actually, if I'm going to use the Arduino libraries, what is wrong with using the entire Arduino IDE for a commercial product? What does programming via the Arduino IDE hide (to make it simpler for the users) that makes it "not trusted" for commercial applications? Or is it a myth?

Comment: Being open source nothing is "hidden" Consider [mbed](https://developer.mbed.org/handbook/Homepage) for more powerful platform in both software and hardware terms.

Comment: Are you asking whether it makes sense to ship the Arduino IDE as part of the commercial product or whether it makes sense to use it just during development?

Comment: Clifford: it's a figure of speech. Thanks, I'll have a look at mbed. @MatthewMurdoch: to use it just during development.

Comment: @Clifford: MBED is certainly too complex for the use of the projects I have in mind. I barely need the USART and ADC, and a 8 bits microcontroller is enough. I try to keep it as simple as I can.

Comment: @Mister Mystère : Do not confuse complexity with scope. While mbed covers a lot of bases, you need not use all of it, and the subset that addresses device access is no more complex than Arduino. It's just a bigger tool-bag; you do not need to use all the tools. In volume, low end Cortex-M parts have comparable cost to 8 bit devices.

Comment: AVR and Arduino are hobbyist orientated. if you need reliability, go after something more industrial orientated, for example, PIC or ARM.

Answer (score 1):

The libraries of Arduino are effective but not efficient. They where developed for users with little knowledge of hardware or software.

For example, take a look at the hardwareSerial.cpp module and see it uses internal loops for sending data, instead of using serial interrupts. This blocks your sketch until it finishes sending data.

Like this example there are some more, and are the reason why i program my own libraries most of the time.

Comment: I guess in this example that would mean the program may hang forever, so it doesn't sound like the libraries themselves are up to industry standard. Does that mean that every single company develops their own libraries and never thought about putting that in common? I'm looking for a good solid API.

Comment: Actually what i do in Arduino is to use its core (with all the `define`, pins names), but not its libraries. I'm not really sure what companies do, but i gess they develop their own libraries, since microcontrollers are very different between them. They probably design different levels of interfaces, and port them for different micros. Most of the time is a one time job.

Comment: What you can do is to look inside Arduino's libraries and make some modifications to optimize them. They are not that bad, just some specific critical functionalities like the one i mentioned. You should change from using wait loops to interrupts, so you get "parallel requests" of data from USART and ADC.

Answer (score 0):

Totally give up the idea that using Arduino lib in a commercial products. Not only because it's in-efficiently, but also because the Thread Safety is not guaranteed. For example, some variables and data-structures (queue) are not protected from ISR context to main context, which may cause data integrity issue or even random Hard Fault. Although the probability is low, you should still give up the idea unless the quality of your products is not important.

On the other hand, low efficiency means you have to pay more hardware budget on the processor, also make it improper in commercial products.

People like Arduino because they want a rapid developing. If you write an solid framework yourself you will be able to develop products fast, also solid.

Comment: Thanks, it's starting to look like Arduino is like I though, "not properly coded because intended to hobbyists". I'm just surprised that there is no one out there that created solid libraries for the AVRs - everyone seems to do their own. MikroC seems to have nice ones but we have to pay for it.

Comment: Linux is an example of solid development, and it's free.